# WCF Service to return simple JSON result

Tags: c#, json, wcf, service

I am trying to figure out the simplest way to return the following JSON string:

```
{"0":"bar1","1":"bar2","2":"bar3"}
```

I'm more than capable of returning something like the following class object to JSON:

```
Person person = new Person()
{
    foo1 = "bar1",
    foo2 = "bar2",
    foo3 = "bar3"
};

{"foo1":"bar1","foo2":"bar2","foo3":"bar3"}
```

I'm just wondering how I would return keys as integer strings instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `[DataMember]` attribute (using the `Name` property) to change the name of the property in the serialized JSON, as shown below.

```
public class StackOverflow_18081074
{
    [DataContract]
    public class Person
    {
        [DataMember(Name = "0")]
        public string Foo1 { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Name = "1")]
        public string Foo2 { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Name = "2")]
        public string Foo3 { get; set; }
    }
    [ServiceContract]
    public class Service
    {
        [WebGet]
        public Person Get()
        {
            return new Person
            {
                Foo1 = "bar1",
                Foo2 = "bar2",
                Foo3 = "bar3"
            };
        }
    }
    public static void Test()
    {
        string baseAddress = "http://" + Environment.MachineName + ":8000/Service";
        WebServiceHost host = new WebServiceHost(typeof(Service), new Uri(baseAddress));
        host.Open();
        Console.WriteLine("Host opened");

        WebClient c = new WebClient();
        Console.WriteLine(c.DownloadString(baseAddress + "/Get"));

        Console.Write("Press ENTER to close the host");
        Console.ReadLine();
        host.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: I shouldn't ask questions on SO when I'm literally half asleep and one eye only works. I knew this. Thank you!